# Nginx doesn't open route defined in proxy_pass for location

Tags: nginx

I am running a NextJS app in production build in docker on nginx server.

Frontend of the app is running on port 3000,
Admin section is running on port 7000,
and Api is running on port 4000

It is working however certain urls are not routed to correct addresses. I will show on mock url and ip

This is nginx.conf in the root folder of my project:

```
http {
  server {
    server_name http://my-website.com/;
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://203.203.203.203:3000;
      rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
    }

    location /admin/ {
      proxy_pass http://203.203.203.203:7000/;
      rewrite ^/admin(.*) /$1 break;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://203.203.203.203:4000/api/;
      rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
    }
  }
}
```

- When I go to http://my-website.com/ it is correct
- When I type http://my-website.com/admin, it shows http://my-website.com/admin/ and the blank page appears (I get 404 GET in network console output)
- When I type http://my-website.com:7000 or http://203.203.203.203:7000 it opens admin page like it should.

The same thing goes with the /api location, when I go to http://my-website.com/api it goes to http://my-website.com/api/ and I get:

```
{
"statusCode": 404,
"message": "Cannot GET /",
"error": "Not Found"
}
```

However when I type http://my-website.com:4000/api it works and http://203.203.203.203:4000/api also works.

Does it have to do with Docker and production build? This is my service in docker-compose:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: production_nginx
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

Or do I need to set up nginx configuration in another place and make it available for build process.

I've also tried in commenting out everything from default files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` to make sure it is not using default configuration

Comment: Try removing the three `rewrite` statements.

Comment: @RichardSmith after removing `rewrite` statements the api part started to work but the admin part won't. Now I have even inserted `depends_on` in the docker-compose.yml and referenced services in `nginx.conf` like `http://admin:7000/` but again everything but admin works